# Webpack and SASS sourcemaps paths issue

Tags: sass, webpack, source-maps

I've make a very simple project to ilustrate the problem.

The project structure is:

[image]

The contents of `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: [
        './src/main.js',
        './src/main.scss'
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'www/'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader?sourceMap'],
            test: /\.scss$/
        }]
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    devServer: {
        contentBase: 'www/'
    }
};
```

The bundle generation is working properly, but when I debug the application, the SASS sourcemaps don't have the right base path:

[image]

Because it nests a second `src/` folder in `src/`. I've tried to add to the `sass-loader` the `sourceMapRoot` option:

```
'sass-loader?sourceMap&sourceMapsRoot=src/'
```

But it doesn't fix the issue. I know it isn't significant, but I want to know if anyone have it working properly or have the same problem.

Best regards, thank you.